# Помогите с управлением C#

Tags: c#

У меня вопрос. Как мне сделать элементы управления на другой форме.
И чтобы они к примеру вылезали с боку от формы, и при нажатии на тогл, прятались назад?
Кнопки например: Добавить пользователя, Таблица заказов и т.п.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то зачем Вам для этого отдельная форма? Добавьте на текущую форму панель, где и разместите все нужные Вам поля, а потом просто постепенно изменяйте отступ панели от верхнего/левого края формы так, чтобы она скрывалась из поля зрения

Comment: Это я знаю, я хочу чтобы они выдвигались с анимацией, поэтому и делаю новую форму. Сослать кнопки с одной формы на другую, просто. А чтобы форма вылазила сбоку от гланвой формы, я не знаю как сделать @Kir_Antipov

Comment: Так а что мешает анимировать панель? Я же говорю, пошагово изменяйте отступ. Это и будет вызывать ощущении анимированного движения